How to limit/customize the number of items that can be seen in a dropdown at a time when using scroll bar to scroll down in PowerApps?
I currently have a dropdown with a list of skills. Currently 8 skills show up as items before I need  to use the scroll bar to view the next set of skills. I want to reduce this to 5 skills but there seems to be no property to do that in PowerApps. Is there a workaround?


Unfortunately no, it's the default one. It will change as per your screen size.
